# Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, pom.xml, spring-framework-beans

I'm new to this.I'm trying to make a Todo List but I keep getting an error and I couldn't fix it. I will be glad if you help. Thanks... I want to save the POJO I created in sqlite, but I keep getting an error.

I can't find the mistake I made.

```
application.properties

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:C:/Java/src/todolist/todolist/Todo.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false
```

```
POM:XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myjavafx</groupId>
    <artifactId>todolist</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>todolist</name>
    <description>Todo List</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>3.0.5</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Hibernate and Jakarta Persistence API Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional Development Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.34.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "todos")
public class Todo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "completed_at")
    private LocalDateTime completedAt;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;

    public enum Status {
        TODO,
        IN_PROGRESS,
        COMPLETED
    }

    // Constructors
    public Todo() {}

    public Todo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = Status.TODO;
        this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() { return createdAt; }
    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) { this.createdAt = createdAt; }

    public LocalDateTime getCompletedAt() { return completedAt; }
    public void setCompletedAt(LocalDateTime completedAt) { this.completedAt = completedAt; }

    public Status getStatus() { return status; }
    public void setStatus(Status status) { this.status = status; }
}
```

I need to access a SQLite database with java. i get this error:

````
org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at com.myjavafx.todolist.TodolistApplication.main(TodolistApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-15T15:02:12.345+02:00 ERROR 15444 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect

Process finished with exit code 0```


I am waiting for the tables to be created in sqlite by doing these operations. and to be able to add and remove in the HTml page I created.
I'm new to this. I'm trying to make a Todo List but I keep getting an error and I couldn't fix it. I will be glad if you help. Thanks...I want to save the POJO I created in sqlite, but I keep getting an error.I'm new to this.I'm trying to make a Todo List but I keep getting an error and I couldn't fix it. I will be glad if you help.Thanks...I want to save the POJO I created in sqlite, but I keep getting an error.
````

Comment: Try this: spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect

Comment: And also, as you a using the newest versions of Spring Boot you should also use Hibernate 6. The best way to manage the versions of Spring Boot dependencies is to use spring-boot-starter-parent with version tag and remove the version tags of other dependencies.